# Datatables not populating with .html() generated table

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I am trying to generate datatables content using .html() however it is not implementing it as actual data. It's adding the rows however they are not searchable or sortable. It says "No data available in table" above the generated results. How can I properly display this generated data in datatables?

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x7ckgo0s/2/)

JS

```
//Payment history
$.ajax({
  url: "https://zelcash.voidr.net/api/payments",
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {

    var _miner = "t1XHpNtYY2N3EMDRoX9RM2hq4DWWPZSmawJ";

    var addr = _miner;

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

      //Name
      console.log(data[i].name);

      var payments = data[i].payments;
      for (var j = 0; j < payments.length; j++) {

        if (payments[j].amounts[_miner]) {

          //Time
          //console.log(payments[j].time);
          var date = payments[j].time;
          var date = new Date(parseInt(date));
          var date = date.toGMTString();

          //blocks
          var block = [];
          var blocks = payments[j].blocks;
          for (var b = 0; b < blocks.length; b++) {
            //console.log(blocks[b])
            block.push(blocks[b]);
          }

          //txid
          var txid = payments[j].txid;

          //amount
          //console.log(payments[j].amounts[_miner]);
          var amount = payments[j].amounts[_miner].toFixed(8);

          var htmlToAdd = "";
          htmlToAdd = '<tr>';
          htmlToAdd+= '<td>'+block+'</td>';
          htmlToAdd+= '<td><a href=\"https://explorer.zel.cash/tx/'+txid+'\">'+amount+'</a></td>';
          htmlToAdd+= '<td>'+date+'</td>';
          htmlToAdd+= '</tr>';
          $("#boxesPayments").html($("#boxesPayments").html()+htmlToAdd);

          //document.querySelector('#boxesPayments').innerHTML += '<tr><td>'+block+'</td><td><a href=\"https://explorer.zel.cash/tx/'+txid+'\">'+amount+'</a></td><td>'+date+'</td></tr>';

        }
      }
    }

  },
  error: function() {
    //alert("Was unable to get info!");
  }
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myTable').DataTable();
});
```

Comment: Need to initialize the plugin **after** you insert the html.

Comment: Hmm can you explain a little more?